# SwiftUI: set background color of the presenting view of a sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way I can specify the background color of the view used to display a sheet in SwiftUI? I know I can set `.background` on my view, but on iPhone X that doesn't affect the safe area. I also could use `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` to fill the area, but I'd prefer not to mess with that.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to rephrase your question. `.background` would solve your problem, but you're *really* looking for a good way to include the safe area in the background color.

Comment: Hmm, yeah wasn't sure how to phrase it... I want to set the `backgroundColor` of the ViewController that's used to present SwiftUI modals.

Answer (score 12):

One more solution is to use a `ZStack`:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingCustomView) {
    ZStack {
        Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        CustomView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In the end you need to deal with `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` since you need to go beyond the safe area (you'd have to do the same in UIKit). The important thing is, that you only ignore the safe area for your background. So in terms of SwiftUI, you only need to apply `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` to the view you pass to `background`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hey there")
            Text("Another line")
        }.background(Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

However, this requires that the view you use `background` on already requests all of the available space (which is not the case in my sample code above), since background only draws a background of the view and does not fill the screen by itself. If that's not the case for you, you need to use e.g. a `ZStack` as shown in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300626/1388842).

Answer (score 5):

Messed with this some more and landed on this solution

```
struct BackgroundFillView<Content: View>: View {
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            self.backgroundColor.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            self.content()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I find this way to resolve that by Introspect, you can find this on https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect and then in your SwiftUI view to do this:

```
YourUIViewController().introspectViewController
{ (viewController) in
 viewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
}
```